# Why Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() returns an additional 0

Tags: c#, vb.net, unicode, encoding, byte

I am converting string to byte using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` but it always add an additional `zero`. here my code is

```
Dim StringBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("s")
```

gives result as

```
115
0
```

Another example:

```
Dim StringBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("mm")
```

gives result as

```
109
0
109
0
```

Why this zero is always added?

Comment: After reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), you will understand the phrase _"Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order"_ as explained on [MSDN: Encoding.Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net uses [Unicode UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (in little-endian byte order) for the value returned from  `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` type, and [UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) uses 2 bytes for each regular character. (UTF16 is also used for the `string` type.)

So for 2 m's you get 4 bytes, a 109 and 0 for each m.

The `0` you are seeing is NOT A NUL TERMINATOR. It's part of the character code.

(Note that for ASCII characters, the UTF16 representation has the high byte set to 0 and the low byte set to the ASCII code of the character. The ASCII code for `m` is 109.)