# How to remove little-endian byte 0 in Java

Tags: java, c#, unicode

#C encodes original myValue before encryption.

```
var myBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myValue);

var encryptedResult = cryptoClient.Encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, myBytes);

var encryptedmyString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedResult.Ciphertext);
```

I need to decrypt it in Java.

```
byte[] code = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedmyString);

DecryptResult decryptionResult = cryptoClient.decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, code);

String result = new String(decryptionResult.getPlainText(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

result has 0 after each byte. I found out this article about little-endian byte [Why Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() returns an additional 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585671/why-encoding-unicode-getbytes-returns-an-additional-0)

How to remove those extra 0 in Java?

**Updated**:

I am not #C developer. I can't change their code.

If I tried this after decryption, it gives me wrong "搀攀瘀栀最愀瀀瀀猀琀漀爀愀最攀戀氀漀戀"

```
new String(decryptionResult.getPlainText(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

Comment: How about encoding the text to UTF8 if you plan to decode it as UTF8 afterwards. Hint: Unicode is __not__ UTF8.

Comment: It seems like the issue you are facing is related to the encoding of the decrypted bytes into a string in Java.

Comment: Updated with more info. This is a best I can get. Not sure what is the correct way to encode the decrypted bytes in java.

Comment: Before encryption in #C, myBytes should have 0 due to little-endian in .Net. I think Unicode uses two encoding forms: 8-bit and 16-bit

Comment: Please show a minimal, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): both `"搀攀瘀栀最愀瀀瀀猀琀漀爀愀最攀戀氀漀戀".encode( 'utf-16-le').decode( 'utf-16-be')` and `"搀攀瘀栀最愀瀀瀀猀琀漀爀愀最攀戀氀漀戀".encode( 'utf-16-be').decode( 'utf-16-le')` return plausible string `devhgappstorageblob`. Use [appropriate charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) instead of `StandardCharsets.UTF_16`. Not sure whether `UTF_16LE` or `UTF_16BE` do apply…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for JosefZ's answer in the comment. It works

```
   new String(decryptionResult_.getPlainText(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```